# Wrong characters when sending mail

Tags: utf-8, php

I have an issue with character settings for the e-mails I send using the mail() function in PHP.

The actual file which I have written the PHP code in is in UTF-8 charset. I have also made sure that charset=UTF-8 is set in the header for the e-mail, I've even added a meta tag in the header for the basic HTML content. Still, it does not work.

This is how the PHP code looks like:

```
// Prepare the e-mail to the GUEST
$to = $email;
$subject = "PÅMINNELSE: Bekräfta registrering för Event";

// Defining the headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Pre-registration <event@adomain.com>" . "\r\n";

include("gemailreminder.php");

// Send the mail now!
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The content of the included file gemailreminder.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$message = <<< MESSAGE
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>REMINDER E-MAIL</title>
</head>
<body>
<p >text...</p >
</body>
</html>
MESSAGE;
?>
```

Any suggestions to help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

//Andreas

Comment: did you used swedish language?

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU Yes, it is Swedish language characters in the e-mail.

Comment: you can change charset=UTF-8"  into charset=ISO-8859-1" it may be help for you

Comment: change this $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU The things is that I do query a database with information that is stored in UTF-8 as well, so my reasoning was that if I do everything consistently in UTF-8 I would not encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Email contents that include non-ascii characters have to be sent with base64 encoding.

This is fairly simple to do using PHP's `base64_encode()` function, but frankly there are too many quirks like this to beware of when using PHP's `mail()` function.

My advice is to use one of the existing classes mailer classes that have been written, which do all the hard work for you -- no more messing with headers, no more worrying about encoding, sending attachments becomes easy, etc etc.

The commonly recommended classes a [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and [phpMailer.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Use either of them, and I guarantee you'll never want to call the bad old `mail()` function directly again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The strange thing is that it has worked, but now suddenly it does not. I will look into how to use the Swiftmailer or phpMailer classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save gemailreminder.php in utf-8, use your editor settings to do that.

Comment: All my PHP files are written in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

For some strange reason it suddenly just started to work again.
Maybe my provider of the webhotel had some issues on their servers or setups for a period of time there.

I thank you for your time and efforts to provide answers. I will still get more familiar with the classes Swiftmailer and phpMail.

Sincerely,
 Andreas